# NHibernate.LazyInitializationException .Net Web API

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to use NHibernate in my project, i am getting the following error
"Initializing[BO.Job#34543]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: BO.Job.bInterview, no session or session was closed". can someone help me.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetbyId(int Id)
        {
            Job job = new Job();
            try
            {
                using (ISession session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())  // Open a session to conect to the database
                {
                    // books = session.Query<Book>().ToList(); //  Querying to get all the jobs
                    JobRepo = new Repo<Job>(session);
                    job = JobRepo.GetById(Id, "Job_selectbyId");
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, job);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Log.Error(exp);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, job);
            }
        }

public T GetById(int id,string SPName)
        {
            T result;
            //return await Task.Run(() =>
            //{
                IQuery query = _session.GetNamedQuery(SPName);
                query.SetParameter("job_id", id);
                //book = _session.Query<Book>().Where(b => b.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                result = query.UniqueResult<T>();
                return result;
            //});
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you're trying to access a property that's been marked as 'lazy' after the session has been closed.

My guess is that you're returning `job` and then the session is being disposed. Some other code is then attempting to access the `Interview` property of the returned `job`, which needs to session to implement the lazy loading feature but the session's been disposed.

You can change you query so that `Interview` is 'pre-fetched' or you can change your mapping so that there's no lazy initialisation on the class or the property.

Comment: job is having foreign key relation with interview table.I tried removing "Lazy" Property in both the hbm.xml files, but still same problem.

Comment: Maybe the mapping cannot influence hydration of the object graph because your query source is a stored proc? To help diagnosing this problem, you could force the `Interview` to be loaded by accessing the property before you return `job`: `job.Interview.SomethingHarmless();`